# For angular material table generate unique id dynamically

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material, mat-table

I have a table which has json data as follows -

```
 {
        "headers":["id","data"],
        "tables": [
            {"data": "1455_456"},
            {"data": "14A8_4546"},
            {"data": "4B54_454546"},
            {"data": "54D5_454"} ,      
            {"data": "545_4D54"} 
        ]
    }
```

Here headers will be the table headers. The tables has the data corresponding to the the data column.

**How can i add values for the id columns so that it has values 1,2,3 and so on?**
The angular material table code is as follows -

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">

    <!--- Note that these columns can be defined in any order.
          The actual rendered columns are set as a property on the row definition" -->
  
    <!-- Position Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> # </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.id}} </td>
    </ng-container>
  
    <ng-container matColumnDef="Data">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> DocumentId </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.data}} </td>
    </ng-container>
  
   
  
    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns; sticky: true"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
  </table>

  <mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 25, 100]" showFirstLastButtons></mat-paginator>
  </div>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Just use the `index` property provided by *ngFor like below inside the HTML and use it to render Ids.

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="id">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> # </th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element; let i = index;"> {{i + 1}} </td>
</ng-container>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to add id like this

In tables array json you can add dynamic id like

```
tables.forEach((o,i)=>o.id=i+1);
```

Hope useful